# Alphanumeric and special character sorting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Select number 
from tableName 
order by Number
```

It displays like below

```
1
10
11
14
14A
14AA
19
2
20
21
```

Instead it should display like below

```
1 
2
10
11
14
14A
14AA
19
20
```

Comment: as you have `14A` and `14AA` in your number column, it treat to that column data as characters.

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL and SQL Server, I have assumed that your column contains only alphanumerics.

**MySQL & SQLite**

```
ORDER BY StrangeCol*1, StrangeCol
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
order by cast(trim(both 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                   from lower(StrangeCol)) as int), StrangeCol
```

**SQL Server**

```
order by 0+stuff(StrangeCol+'a',patindex('%[a-Z]%',StrangeCol+'a'),999,''), StrangeCol
```

**Oracle**

```
order by 0+regexp_replace(StrangeCol, '[^[:digit:]]') ,StrangeCol
```

Comment: I can't speak for all the examples, but the sql server part fails

Comment: @t-cl What's your definition of `fail`? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d127c/3/0

Comment: This is really strange, every time i run your script on 2008. It fails with 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14AA' to data type int.'

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Fiddle link in my previous comment?

Comment: yes i have, it works on my 2000(80) but fails on my 2008(100), very interesting. Error i am getting is: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14AA' to data type int.

Comment: my database is funny, your script works perfect. But it fails on my base, when i changed 14AA to 14AB it worked. Thanks for your time

Comment: mystery solved. Reason it failed was the collation(Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS). It doesn't consider 'AA' as 2 a's, but rather it is the letter 'Å'. Characters that are not alphanumeric will cause the query to fail with error. Try with '14#'

Answer (score 2):

you could try this horrible thing. Which proves that it would be better to store these values in two fields...

```
ORDER BY
CAST(SUBSTRING(Number, 0, 
  case when patindex('%[a-zA-Z]%', Number) = 0 
  then len(Number)+1
  else patindex('%[a-zA-Z]%', Number)
  end) 
as INT),
Number
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ead5a/1)

Comment: This is incorrect. It will put `20` before `14AA`

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi you're right, edited.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk could you show me a failing example ? Did you see the SqlFiddle ?

Comment: I appologize my database is acting funny, upvoted

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
create table tblNum(id varchar(10))

insert into tblNum 
values('1'),('10'),('11'),('14'),('14A'),('14AA'),('19'),('2'),('20'),('21')

select id from tblNum order by 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',id) > 0 then cast(left(id,(PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',id)-1)) as int) else cast(id as int) end
```

Comment: @Downvoter - give comment simply downvoting will not be a good practice

Comment: I appologize my database is acting funny. For some reason it gave the wrong result. Same error as @RichardTheKiwi

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify the type of your ordering. e.g in 14AA you said the first part interpreted as number and second part as alphabetic!!

If you want to mix them I suggest to use HEX base.